# Uploading straight to bucket

Tags: autodesk-forge

Can't find a way to to upload file directly to bucket instead of submiting file to PHP backend and then forwarding it from backend to bucket.

Is there a way to do this with 2-legged token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is but for security reasons the recommended approach is to upload from client to backend and from backend to Forge. The reason is to avoid sending a token with `data:write` or `data:create` privileges to the client, which would allow an attacker to mess up with the data present on those buckets.

If you want to do it from client however, the only thing you need to do is to generate a token from your backend, expose an endpoint for your client to access it and perform a REST call from the client using the token and that endpoint: [PUT buckets/:bucketKey/objects/:objectName](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-:objectName-PUT/)

Comment: That's what I need. Thanks!